# Number object from http request returns date type or similar

Tags: google-apps-script

I make a Facebook API call in Google scripts to get the share count for a URL. It appears that the number (e.g. `31`) is being found correctly, but when I pass it to Sheets, it shows e.g. `30/01/1900` in the sheets box.

My appScript code is:

```
function getShareCount(url) {
  var url = "https://any.org/111";
  var inputurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/?id=" + url + "&access_token=XXXXXXXX";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(inputurl);
  var response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var response = response.share.share_count;
  Utilities.sleep(500);
  return response;
}
```

and the spreadsheet box has: `"=getShareCount(B2)"`

If I purposefully break the code and run the debugger in script Apps, I can see that script apps is getting a response with `Number`: `31`. If I change to e.g. "response.id", the URL is returned into sheets as expected. The same with other parts of the object. Those are strings, and this is a number. I can't work out what sort of object sheets is receiving, nor what method I can use to simply show the number `311.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your cell has a custom format of Date. Select the cells you want to format and click **Format > Number > Automatic**